# Elasticsearch filter where poi nearby

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6

I want to perform the following pseudo query on Elastic:

```
SELECT SomeTypeOfObjects WHERE distance to 
PointOfInterests < 20km AND PointOfInterests.type = 'bar';
```

I have the following data in Elastic:

```
SomeTypeOfObjects (around 10.000.000 rows)
----------
id = x
geo_location = x,x

PointOfInterests( around 400.000 rows )
---------
id = x
geo_location = x,x
type=bar, hospital, etc
```

Would this be possible without 2 queries or feeding the query all possible geo locations?

Answer (score 0):

If you saved your lat,lon as [geo-point](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-point.html), you should be able to execute a [`geo_distance`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-geo-distance-query.html) query like this:

```
GET /my_locations/location/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : {
                "match_all" : {}
            },
            "filter" : {
                "geo_distance" : {
                    "distance" : "12km",
                    "pin.location" : {
                        "lat" : 40,
                        "lon" : -70
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which apparently doesn't answer your question. I guess the best option would be to
1. Get coordinates of all bars
2. Use geo_distance with multiple points:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-geo-distance-query.html